# Buscar en archivo de excel un valor y darme detalles de la fila

Tags: python, excel

Saludos soy nuevo en python, tengo que hacer un ejercicio el cual es buscar un valor en una tabla de excel, al encontrarlo deseo obtener los valores de esa fila donde esta alojado el valor que se busco, he tratado de ayudarme con algunos ejemplos pero no he llegado lejos, me sale error alguien me puede ayudar.

deseo buscar de la tabla con el dato idN

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'productos.xls',
    header=0,
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    skiprows=2,
    usecols="A:E"
    )

while busqueda:= input('Buscar por numero de ingreso: '):
    cont = df[df['idN'] == busqueda]
    if not cont.empty:
        print('¡El contenedor se ha encuentrado!')
        print(precio)
        print(detalle)
    
    else:
        print('¡El contenedor no se ha encontrado!\n')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Yo veo varios errores:

1.- Estás usando `pd.read_excel` con los siguientes parámetros equivocados:

a.- `sheet_name='Hoja1'` : Esto te devuelve los datos de la hoja excel con el nombre indicado, y tu hoja se llama de otra forma ('productos_excel'). Si solo tienes una hoja en tu archivo excel, puedes omitir este parámetro.

b.- `skiprows=2` : Esto impide la carga de las dos primeras líneas de tu tabla, por lo que NO podrás encontrar esos datos. Si quieres buscar en toda la tabla, debes omitir ese parámetro.

c.- `usecols="A:E"` : Esto carga las columnas desde 'A', hasta 'E' de tu excel, pero en la columna E no hay datos. Si omites este parámetro, se cargarán en Python todas las columnas con datos.

2.- Las variables en Python `precio` y `detalle`, no las has definido previamente, ni les asignas ningún valor, así que no se imprimirá nada aunque la variable de búsqueda encuentre algo.

Ya casi lo tienes, así que te dejo que investigues un poco. Si necesitas más ayuda, comenta.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que ya no te sirva mi respuesta, pero si a alguien le sirviese, se me ocurre que para que puedas obtener los valores de la fila que coinciden con el valor buscado, se podría intentar lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(
    'productos.xls',
    header=0,
    sheet_name='Hoja1',
    skiprows=2,
    usecols="A:E"
    )

busqueda = input('Buscar por numero de ingreso: ')
cont = df[df['idN'] == int(busqueda)]

if not cont.empty:
    print('¡El contenedor se ha encontrado!')
    fila = cont.iloc[0]
    precio = fila['precio']
    detalle = fila['detalle']
    print(precio)
    print(detalle)
else:
    print('¡El contenedor no se ha encontrado!\n')
```

Asegúrate de convertir el valor buscado a `int` antes de usarlo para la comparación. Además, utiliza `iloc[0]` para obtener la primera fila de los resultados. Por último, si tienes múltiples filas que coinciden con el valor buscado, deberías usar un bucle para recorrer cada una de ellas. Saludos!